# How to list all "Cast is redundant" messages?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm want to check if some code has redundant typecasts in Visual Studio 2015. Is there a way to list all the redundant typecast warning messages? I dug around in the Error List window but found nothing. I imagine there should be a windows that lists all the non-essential warnings/messages including redundant `using`s and such. Is there such a window?

Comment: There is not such thing as a "non-fatal warning". All warnings are in the error list. If there's no warning in the list, there's no warning.

Comment: Also, you won't find any redundant typecasts in the compiled code.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I don't think OP is interested in analyzing compiled code.

Comment: ReSharper has this functionality in the menu RESHARPER -> Inspect -> Code Issues in Solution. You might need to alter the filtering.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar edited to remove what you mentioned.

Comment: and @itsme86 thanks for the suggestion, but I don't have ReSharper. And I can't get it either. I'm not a student and what I'm working on isn't open source either. Any other ideas? I'm starting to think I'm just going to have to do it manually.

Comment: As @JeroenvanLangen already mentioned, removing redundant casts is just additional work. The compiler will not include code for a cast if the cast is redundant. So even *if* redundant casts don't cause a warning to be shown, you could remove them whenever you see one, otherwise leave them alone. To answer the question (again): There's only just one window that displays warnings. If there's no warning about the redundant cast there, then no warning is created for redundant casts.

Comment: Thanks @ThorstenDittmar.